# MySQL query executes too long. Query returns good results, but maybe it is not good designed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

here is the SQL Fiddle for my problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ad87/2

I have tables: **groups**, **offers** and **offers_groups**.

Groups have names, but those names have special id's assigned to them. Id's are not auto incrementing, they are predefined that way.

Here is a very small part of **groups** table:

`id         name
 0300000    Agro
 0310000    Fruits
 0311000    Peach
 0320000    Vegetables`

In **offers** table are stored offers made by people and companies:

`id     offer
 1      Selling fruits
 2      Selling peanuts
 3      Selling Vegetables
 4      Selling peach
 5      We do Agro
 6      We sell Peach
 7      We sell Vegetables
 8      We transport Vegetables
 9      We transport Peaches`

and **offers_groups** table is responsible for connecting these two:

`id     offer_id    group_id
1       1           3100000
2       2           0300000
3       3           0311000
4       4           0300000
5       5           0311000
6       6           0320000
7       7           0320000
8       3           0311000`

I need to calculate what groups have the most offers and display those groups to users.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT og.id, og.offer_id, og.group_id,
       o.id, o.offer,
       g.id, g.name,
       COUNT(og.offer_id) AS offersCount

FROM `offers_groups` og 

JOIN `offers` o ON og.offer_id = o.id
JOIN `groups` g ON og.group_id = g.id

GROUP BY og.group_id

ORDER BY offersCount DESC

LIMIT 2
```

Code in my SQL Fiddle is working, I think it is giving me the right result, but in real database where these tables have a lot of data, this query is executing 25 seconds. And I do not believe that it is because of column indexing, right ? I am hoping that some expert can tell me if my query is badly designed. Can I do something to speed things up while getting the right result ?

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind adding your query to the question? If the Fiddle website goes down tomorrow, this question will no longer make any sense to future readers. If you can make questions as self-contained as possible (with a Fiddle as well), that's ideal.

Comment: How many rows do you have in each of your live tables?

Comment: can you show us the sql query you are executing? give us the fiddle path so that we can see ourself?

Comment: Aside from your PK indexes, you don't have any indexes at all. I should think that is the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question with query executed. I thought that I gave fiddle path at the top of post o.O

Comment: In groups table there is 10.000 rows, in other two about 2.000 each

Comment: A have added indexes to groups.id and offers_groups.group_id, but it's not helping :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all the columns in  your `select` do not make sense.  They should only be at the "group" level, not at the "offer group" level.  So, let me focus on this query:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name,
       COUNT(og.offer_id) AS offersCount
FROM `offers_groups` og JOIN
     `offers` o
     ON og.offer_id = o.id JOIN
     `groups` g
     ON og.group_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY offersCount DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Second, in any reasonably structured database, you don't actually need the `offers` table -- the foreign key relationships should ensure that the rows actually exist.  So, try this:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name,
       COUNT(og.offer_id) AS offersCount
FROM `offers_groups` og JOIN
     `groups` g
     ON og.group_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY offersCount DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Then, based on your SQL Fiddle, you have no indexes on your tables.  Define all the `id` to be primary keys.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `offer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

The use of primary keys should fix your performance problems.

Comment: Thank you, your second query is executing fast in phpmyadmin, but in my application is still slow. I guess I will have to figure that out.

Comment: Its fully fixed now, my bad.. ty